# Black screen and no sound after login

Tags: 11.10, sound, gnome, brightness

My notebook is Asus U31SD and I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell and I'm having this weird problem that after login I can hear start sound and I barely see the desktop. To fix it I need  to press every time <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (more brightness).

I have tried to modify `rc.local` by adding

`echo 0(or 10) > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Here is the rc.local file:

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    # 
    # rc.local
    echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

but I don't know why it doesn't work. If i do an `echo` from terminal command is working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The way you've written it, it sounds like you're literally writing "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness" to `rc.local`. Is this the case, or are you running this command from the command line?

Comment: I have modified first post to include rc.local file.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at /var/log/boot.log to see if there's an error reported. It's probably not rc.local not working, but the script fails to work when rc.local is loaded.

At least it's what I encountered.

I added

```
chown ****(my username) /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

to rc.local (and set rc.local to executable). And then I got

```
chown: cannot access `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch': No such file or directory
```

in the boot.log, which seemed to indicate the script was run before the switching mechanism was set up.